# Maven Multi Module Project in SVN

Tags: java, svn, maven, maven-3

I Created a Maven Multi Module project in my local system. After that I uploaded that into a SVN repository. When I checking out that project from SVN by using eclipse it's checking out as a single project. How can I convert it as Maven Multi Module Project ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Install [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) and [m2eclipse-subclipse connector](https://github.com/markphip/m2eclipse-subclipse)* then use [Checkout Maven projects from SCM](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Importing+Maven+projects#ImportingMavenprojects-CheckoutMavenprojectsfromSCM).

> "File / Import... / Other / Checkout Maven projects from SCM..."

Alternatively there is also a [connector](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Subversive) for subversive.

---

For projects in your local file system:

> "File / Import..." and then choose "Maven Projects"

Answer (score 0):

In case of large projects with many developers involved, it can be tedious to check out all modules and keep them up to date. Especially if you are only interested in one or two modules. In this case using binary dependencies is much more comfortable. Just check out the modules you want to work on with Eclipse and `run mvn eclipse:eclipse` for each module (see also [Maven as an external tool](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you show more about you pom.xml, this is a guideline to create the Multimodule project: Multimodule , as it's way that it should use parent pom to include the multiple project. actually in our projects that we use this way, but I still recommend you to separate you project and inject it to the pom.xml. then you can just check our 1 project that you want to use. BTW, you can install the eclipse maven plugin to make this easier.